# Call JS variable in HTML specific div file based on if and else condition

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 variables contain data i need to call in HTML based on js logic, can you check and fix code for me what i am missing.

```
${specialprice} and ${price}
```

I need javascript condition to be define in javascript file and call it in html. ( JS file already connected to html )

What i need is to complete this logic is if ${specialprice} contain any value then show it together with ${price}

if is empty then show only ${price}.

condition in JS File:

```
hasspecialprice() {  
    if(${specialprice} != ''){
            var data = "<p class="specialprice">"۔${specialprice}",-</p>
            <p class="price"><span class="visibleprice">"۔${price}",-</span></p>"
         }
         else
         {
            var data = "<p class="price"><span class="visibleprice">".${price}",-</span></p>"
    }
}
```

Call this function in HTML:

```
 <div class="priceplace">
              <script>hasspecialprice();</script>
</div>
```

Comment: looking at your profile, your way of thinking is from php-way approach? are you sure ur js is valid? `{` and `}` are not valid for variable name.

Comment: yes they are correct, these variables are from online platform javascript where i need to execute them and works fine as well! not in regular javascript.

Comment: What is this "online platform javascript" that you are using - is there a question tag for it? Perhaps you should remove the "javascript" tag from the question.

Comment: true, but on this online platform it says JS and i can see other JS conditions working as well based on values passed through mentioned variables!

Comment: The syntax `${expression}` (where expression can be variable name) is only used within [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which themselves must start and end with backticks ('`\``') in JS source. Try pressing **F12** to open the developer's console and click on the "console" tab to see if the source code has errors in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could change the content of a div dynamically using js. The important thing to note (besides the corrected syntax) is that I selected the output-target in js and then updated it's content based on the relevant values.

```js
// select the form used for the demo
const form = document.querySelector('form');
// select the output div
const target = document.querySelector('.priceplace');
// define our example data
const data = {
    price: 0,
    specialprice: 0
};

// when a formfield is changed, we change our example data and update the output
form.onchange = ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    data[name] = value;
    hasspecialprice(data.price, data.specialprice);
};

function hasspecialprice(price, specialprice) {
    // using a ternary expression is equivalent to a simple if/else
    // we change the output's html based on the condition
    target.innerHTML = specialprice !== '' 
        ? `<p class="specialprice">${specialprice},-</p>
        <p class="price"><span class="visibleprice">${price},-</span></p>`
        : `<p class="price"><span class="visibleprice">${price},-</span></p>`
}
```

```html
<form>
    Specialprice:
    <input name="specialprice">
    Price:
    <input name="price">
</form>

<div class="priceplace" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 16px"></div>
```

Comment: code looks great,but can you re-edit it and remove form requriement, since values are already passed dynamically into those variable names

${specialprice} and ${price}

Comment: @Mr.Devops The form is only there to have a usable snippet, it's not required to use the function. If you already have the values, then just call the function with them.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript code you dont need to use the `${}` statement. The `${}` only uses when you need to concatenate string with variables. You only need to remove this from your if statement. You could improve to use

```
hasspecialprice() {  
    if(specialprice != ''){
            var data = "<p class="specialprice">"۔${specialprice}",-</p>
            <p class="price"><span class="visibleprice">"۔${price}",-</span></p>"
         }
         else
         {
            var data = "<p class="price"><span class="visibleprice">".${price}",-</span></p>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If have an way to call the hasspecialprice() function then you must try this.

```
    hasspecialprice() {  
    const inputDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("priceplace");
    
    if(${specialprice} != ''){
        var pElement = document.createElement('p');   //  CREATING AN ELEMENT
        pElement.className += "specialprice"; //  ADDING CLASSE TO IT
        pElement.innerText = specialprice;  //  ADDING DATA TO IT

        var secondPElement = document.createElement('p');   
        secondPElement.className += "price"; 
        var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
        spanElement.className += "visibleprice"; 
        spanElement.innerText = price;

        inputDiv.append(pElement);
        secondPElement.appendChild(spanElement);
        inputDiv.append(secondPElement);     
    }
        else{
        var secondPElement = document.createElement('p');   
        secondPElement.className += "price"; 
        var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
        spanElement.className += "visibleprice"; 
        spanElement.innerText = price;

        secondPElement.appendChild(spanElement);
        inputDiv.append(secondPElement);   
    }
}
```